# Datatable per column select box filter not working

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I checked code there is no any error in the console but it not displaying Select box in table footer how can I resolve this please help me. Thanks in advance for watching my question. and sorry for my weak English.

Datatable code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#property').DataTable( {
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                            $(this).val()
                        );

                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );

                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        }
    } );
} );
```

Html Code:

```
<table  class="display table dataTable table-bordered table-striped" id="property" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
  <tr>
      <th style="font-style: uppercase;color:red;">ID</th>
      <th style="font-style: uppercase;color:red;">PROPERTY FOR</th>
      <th style="font-style: uppercase;color:red;">PROPERTY TYPE</th>
      <th style="font-style: uppercase;color:red;">BHK</th>
      <th style="font-style: uppercase;color:red;">RENT AMOUNT</th>
      <th style="font-style: uppercase;color:red;">SELL AMOUNT</th>
      <th style="font-style: uppercase;color:red;">LOCALITY</th>
      <th style="font-style: uppercase;color:red;">AREA</th>
      <th style="font-style: uppercase;color:red;">SOCITEY</th>
      <th style="font-style: uppercase;color:red;">OWNER TYPE</th>
      <th style="font-style: uppercase;color:red;">NAME</th>
      <th style="font-style: uppercase;color:red;">CONTACT</th>
      <th style="font-style: uppercase;color:red;">MONTH</th>
      <th style="font-style: uppercase;color:red;">ACTION</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php foreach($datas as $data):?>
    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td style="color:#000;font-size:15px"><?php echo $data['ID'];?></td>
        <td style="color:#000;font-size:15px"><?php if($data['Property_for'] == 1){echo 'Sell';}else{echo 'Rent';} ?></td>
        <td style="color:#000;font-size:15px"><?php echo $data['Property_name'];?></td>
        <td style="color:#000;font-size:15px"><?php echo $data['BHK'];?></td>
        <td style="color:#000;font-size:15px"><?php echo $data['Monthly_rent'];?></td>
        <td style="color:#000;font-size:15px"><?php echo $data['Sellprice'];?></td>
        <td style="color:#000;font-size:15px"><?php echo $data['Area'];?></td>
        <td style="color:#000;font-size:15px"><?php echo $data['Builtup'].' '.$data['Unit_name'];?></td>
        <td style="color:#000;font-size:15px"><?php echo $data['Socitey'];?></td>
        <td style="color:#000;font-size:15px"><?php echo $data['Owner_Type'];?></td>
        <td style="color:#000;font-size:15px"><?php echo $data['Owner_name'];?></td>
        <td style="color:#000;font-size:15px"><?php echo $data['Owner_Mobile'];?></td>
        <td style="color:#000;font-size:15px"><?php echo date("M", strtotime($data['Create_date']));?></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" id="<?php echo $data['ID']?>" onClick="deleteproperty(this.id)"><i class="icon-trash"></i></button><?php if($view == 'Close'):?><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" id="<?php echo $data['ID']?>" onClick="openproperty(this.id)"><i class="icon-expand-alt"></i></button><?php else:?><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" id="<?php echo $data['ID']?>" onClick="closeproperty(this.id)"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button><?php endif;?><a href="http://www.kakaproperty.com/View/Property/<?php echo $data['ID']?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="icon-expand"></i></button></a></td>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach;?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `tfoot` element in your markup.

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/wgg6zgL9/) for code and demonstration.